# Where can I get the source code for stackoverflow.com's WMD version?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, editor, source-code

I think the question is self-explanatory - its not that that I want SO source code.  What I am looking for is how they added `image upload from PC` feature. I need to implement it too.

Comment: Belongs on Meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's here: http://github.com/derobins/wmd

Comment: This link does not have the latest image upload feature.